# Test Case for GWT MVP with Activities and Places and GIN using Mockito

Tags: java, gwt, junit, mvp, mockito

I am new to GWT MVP Pattern with Activities and Places with the combination of GIN. I have started attempting to write a JUnit test case for my GWT project using Mockito. A lot of blogs suggested that I do not use GWT Test Case because of its performance so I planned on sticking to Mockito. I am writing a test case for one of the Presenters. Since I am using GIN to create instance for most of the things in my Presenter I have to mock my Gin Injector object. My Junit Test Case is not allowing me to mock the Gin injector. I read somewhere that we cannot use Gin in the Junit Test Case instead we have to go with Guice. My question is that how do I mock my Gin injector using Mockito? I found some Test Case which used the exact same pattern that I did for my project except that they used Client Factory instead. I have failed in replacing the Client factory with GIN in the test case. The code that I found online is as follows and I have to replace Client Factory with GIN injector in my Test Case.

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ContactListActivityTest {

```
@Mock
private IClientFactory clientFactoryMock;

@Mock
private PlaceController placeControllerMock;

@Mock
private IContactListView contactListViewMock;

@Mock
private AcceptsOneWidget acceptsOneWidgetMock;

@Mock
private IContactServiceAsync contactServiceAsyncMock;

@Mock
private EventBus eventBusMock;

private List<Contact> contacts;
private Contact contact1;
private Contact contact2;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    when(clientFactoryMock.getPlaceController()).thenReturn(placeControllerMock);
    when(clientFactoryMock.getContactListView()).thenReturn(contactListViewMock);
    when(clientFactoryMock.getContactService()).thenReturn(contactServiceAsyncMock);

    Answer<Void> answer = new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            AsyncCallback<List<Contact>> asyncCallback = (AsyncCallback<List<Contact>>) args[0];
            contact1 = new Contact();
            contact1.setFirstName("Kai");
            contact1.setLastName("Toedter");
            contact1.setEmail("kai@toedter.com");
            contact2 = new Contact();
            contact2.setFirstName("Kai2");
            contact2.setLastName("Toedter2");
            contact2.setEmail("kai2@toedter.com");
            final List<Contact> contacts2 = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            contacts2.add(contact1);
            contacts2.add(contact2);
            asyncCallback.onSuccess(contacts2);
            return null;
        }
    };

    doAnswer(answer).when(contactServiceAsyncMock).getAllContacts(any(AsyncCallback.class));

    // set the real contacts object, when clientFactory.setContacts is
    // called
    Answer<Void> setContactsAnswer = new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            contacts = (List<Contact>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            // System.out.println("answer() to setContacts(): " + contacts);
            return null;
        }
    };

    doAnswer(setContactsAnswer).when(clientFactoryMock).setContacts(any(List.class));

    // Return the real contacts object, when clientFactory.getContacts is
    // called
    Answer<List<Contact>> getContactsAnswer = new Answer<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Contact> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return contacts;
        }
    };

    doAnswer(getContactsAnswer).when(clientFactoryMock).getContacts();
}

@Test
public void testGotoPlace() {
    ContactListActivity contactListActivity = new ContactListActivity(new ContactPlace(null), clientFactoryMock);

    ContactPlace contactPlace = new ContactPlace("kai@toedter.com");
    contactListActivity.goTo(contactPlace);

    verify(placeControllerMock).goTo(contactPlace);
}

@Test
public void testStartWithEmptyToken() {
    clientFactoryMock.setContacts(null); // force RCP
    ContactListActivity contactListActivity = new ContactListActivity(new ContactPlace(""), clientFactoryMock);
    contactListActivity.start(acceptsOneWidgetMock, eventBusMock);

    verify(contactListViewMock).setPresenter(contactListActivity);
    verify(contactListViewMock).initialize(contacts);
}

@Test
public void testStartWithToken() {
    String token = "kai@toedter.com";
    clientFactoryMock.setContacts(null); // force RCP

    ContactListActivity contactListActivity = new ContactListActivity(new ContactPlace(token), clientFactoryMock);
    contactListActivity.start(acceptsOneWidgetMock, eventBusMock);

    verify(contactListViewMock).setPresenter(contactListActivity);
    verify(contactListViewMock).initialize(contacts);
    verify(contactListViewMock).selectInitialContact(contact1);
    verify(eventBusMock).fireEvent(any(ContactViewEvent.class));
}

@Test
public void testMayStop() {
    ContactListActivity contactListActivity = new ContactListActivity(new ContactPlace(null), clientFactoryMock);
    contactListActivity.start(acceptsOneWidgetMock, eventBusMock);
    contactListActivity.mayStop();

    verify(contactListViewMock).setPresenter(null);
}

@Test
public void clientFactoryTest() {
    List<Contact> testList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    clientFactoryMock.setContacts(testList);
    Assert.assertNotNull(clientFactoryMock.getContacts());
}
```

}

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

If your code depends on the `Ginjector`, then you have a problem: you're not injecting [direct dependencies](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectOnlyDirectDependencies). If you need a factory of objects, inject a `Provider`.

But in your case, `IClientFactory` also serves as a *shared state*, a *value holder* or *local cache* for a `List<Contact>`; which means `IClientFactory` violates the [single responsibility principle](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle&ei=RFlIUPOKMaG_0QXyz4CIAg&usg=AFQjCNFoci3JyHtoEwOx1lduCbF7IcS50Q&sig2=oO-j6HqkrtmSxNbb8_AcZQ).

So, first extract the *local cache* responsibility into its own object (e.g. a `ContactListCache` object, or a more generic `ValueHolder<List<Contact>>`) then inject an instance of that object.
And of course, inject the `PlaceController`, view and GWT-RPC service directly.

But actually, I'd go farther and refactor the code to extract the *retrieve from cache or ask the server* responsibility into its own `ContactListHolder` object (or, as you're using GWT-RPC, you could implement the `IContactServiceAsync` interface as a wrapper around the one generated by `GWT.create()` and that adds the caching behavior; see http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html for some inspiration). That would simplify the activity's code a lot.

---

As a side note, this code probable makes too much use of mocking: why not using the real `PlaceController` (and `spy()`ing its `goTo(Place)` method) and a `SimpleEventBus` or `CountingEventBus`?

Comment: Hi Thomas... I can remove indirect dependencies of injector from my code and just send the instance of what I need from the injector instead. My main question is that if it is possible for me to use Gin in a Junit Test Case. I am new to Junit Test Cases too. I do not know if it is possible for me to mock Gin injector at all or not. And this is just an example I found . I will not be using getContactList from ClientFactory or Gin injector. Its only the instances of the Views that I am actually interested in. Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: A GIN injector is no more than an interface, so you can mock it like anything else. You'd have to provide the answers for the methods though. But as I said, you shouldn't have to do it in your code; it's a code-smell if you need a Ginjector instance outside of the `onModuleLoad` (which you won't unit-test).

Comment: Hi Thomas. I replaced Gin injector with Client Factory and my test case runs fine. The moment I say @Mock BodDeskGinjector injector the test case throws an error saying java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Er, do you have something like `BodDeskGinjector INSTANCE = GWT.create(BodDeskInjector.class)` **inside** your `BodDeskInjector` interface? If so, remove it, and move it to your `onModuleLoad()`.

Comment: Hi Thomas..Thanks that was the problem indeed....I fixed it and now GWT Ginjector works perfect in place of ClientFactory. I read it somewhere that we cannot GIN in Junit which caused all the confusion.Thanks a ton for all the help.. Cheers

Comment: Well, you indeed cannot "use GIN", but the _magic_ happens in `GWT.create()`, otherwise a `Ginjector` is just an interface with some annotations.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is to use **GwtMockito** which is an extension of Mockito. In the only one class that I use my injector, my test looks like this

```
@RunWith(GwtMockitoTestRunner.class)
public class AppControllerTest {

    AppController controller;

    @Mock
    EventBus eventBus;

    @Mock
    AppInjector injector;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUseInjector() throws Exception {
        // Given
        controller = new AppController(eventBus, injector);

        // When
        controller.go();

        // Verify
        verify(injector).mainPresenter();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even the eventBus can be get from the injector :S, so just giving the injector in the constructor is enough for me